# Significance test for an image centroid

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, image-processing

I have an n x n matrix. Each cell contains a value. The matrix is essentially a heatmap. The null hypothesis is that the greatest values would be at the horizontal and vertical midlines of the matrix. Let's say that n is odd. Then, the columns of the matrix would correspond to x = -(n-1)/2 : (n-1) / 2. The rows would correspond to y = -(n-1)/2 : (n-1) / 2. And therefore the middle column and middle row would correspond to x = 0 and y = 0, respectively. The null hypothesis is that the hottest cells would lie close to x = 0 and y = 0. The alternative hypothesis is that the hottest cells are off both midlines, in other words, displaced from the origin.

I can use a weighted centroid to find the center of mass of the matrix. But what sort of significance test could I use to confirm the alternative hypothesis?

Edit:
Regarding the null hypothesis.
The null hypothesis is as follows. Take triples (a,b,c) <-- [1, 100]^3. In other words for each triple, a,b,c are taken from the uniform distribution on [1, 100]. then, let x = a-b, and y = b-c. So, when many random triples are obtained, x and y are assigned, and the results are plotted, you actually have a distribution that favors the top left and bottom right quadrants, and appears relatively more rarely in the bottom left and top right quadrants. An example is below.

[image: Null distribution]

Comment: For hypothesis testing, you must know the distribution of the values under the null hypothesis. What do you know about the heat distribution? Ist it normally distributed around the center?

Comment: The distribution is probably not quite normal. Rather, it's more like a sharp peak, (not a round, bell-shaped one), with the peak close to zero but not quite.

Comment: It would help to have a clearer indication of what the *alternative* hypothesis might be: in versions of this heatmap that don't adhere to your null hypothesis, what are the possible patterns like?

Comment: The null hypothesis is as follows. Take triples (a,b,c) <-- [1, 100]^3. In other words for each triple, a,b,c are taken from the uniform distribution on [1, 100]. then, let x = a-b, and y = b-c. So, when many random triples are obtained, x and y are assigned, and the results are plotted, you actually have a distribution that favors the top left and bottom right quadrants, and appears relatively more rarely in the bottom left and top right quadrants. 

I've included an image in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not have a well-defined null hypothesis $H_0$ (you do not know the distribution under $H_0$), there is no way to compute the probability of the observation under $H_0$.

Under the assumption, however, that the "heat map" $h(x,y)$ actually is a probability distribution, i.e.
$$P(X=x, Y=y)\sim h(x,y)$$
or, equivalently
$$P(X=x,Y=y)=\frac{h(x,y)}{\sum_{x',y'}h(x',y')}$$
you could, do something in the spirit of statistical hypothesis testing and check whether the origin $(x,y)=(0,0)$ falls into a region of low probability as follows:

1. Compute the probability of the region that is outside the ellipsis with $h(x,y)=h(0,0)$.
2. Consider the mean value $\sum_{x,y} (x,y)\cdot P(X=x,Y=y)$ as "significantly different" from $(0,0)$, if the probability of the outer region is below some threshold (e.g. 0.01).

Whether it is a good idea to extend the most dubious aspect of hypothesis testing to this application, is a different question, though: hypothesis testing asks for the probability of an event you have not observed (that the deviation from an assumed value is *greater* than the observed deviation) under an assumption that you know to be false (the null hypothesis) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I might be way off depending on what you are actually trying to do. Maybe you can use some sort of a bootstrap method. It is quite hard to tell how exactly to do this unless we know your sampling method - we have to know what gives rise to the random error in your data. I will anyway take a crack at it making some assumption about your study design.

From what I understand from the question, as the distance of the weighted centroid from the origin increases, the probability of the null being true decreases. If this is the case, maybe one can do the following. I will represent it as a simple 5x5 matrix for easier explanation.

[image: Your dataset]

1. Weighted centroid should be centered at the origin by subtracting the x value of the centroid from the x value of all cells and subtracting y value of the centroid from the y value of all cells. This is your null distribution.

[image: Weighted centroid at zero (Null distribution)]

2. Randomly sample the cells with replacement and compute the weighted centroid for the resampled dataset. Do this like a thousand times and get a distribution of weighted centroid values around the origin and their distances to the origin.

[image: Distribution of resampled centroids]
3) Find the number of times the simulated centroids were further away from the origin than your original centroid. Divide this number by the number of resampling iterations (1000 maybe?). This is your p value.

This is assuming that the error in your data comes from what x and y values you sample. I also assume weighted centroid is a good parameter to test your hypothesis. I am not sure if that is the case. Also, p values might not be the best way to determine statistical significance in this case.

Elaborating more about your study might help in deciding what type of resampling to do.

Comment: Thank you, this certainly sounds reasonable. I think this is a perfectly valid approach. Although, I was looking for more of an "absolute" versus an "empiric" test, if that makes sense.

Comment: @amd1972 as multiple people before have noted, you will need a well-defined null distribution for an "absolute" solution - if I understand what you mean by null distribution. Tests using Monte-Carlo methods are usually impervious to the type of distribution.